# Adding images next to text in html

Tags: html

I currently have one image and a video in my html and I want them to be in the same section as my text (which I have achieved) however currently the image is on top of the video and the text. I am trying to get it so the image is above the video and both are to the left of the text. Can anyone help please??? [This is my css.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4crFS.jpg)
[This is my html.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4BLz.jpg)

Comment: you need to post actual code and not images of it. Nobody's going to retype that, certainly not me anyway.

Comment: ^ As above, please copy relevant code into your question.

Comment: so, the longer you wait, the more time it takes. I for one have now left the question; good luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

In css (for all images, if you don't want it like that then use class or id)

```
img {
    float:left;
}
iframe {
    float:left;
}
```

[W3School example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_layout_float)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be really specific so as not to effect all elements on your page I'd go with:

```
.indexmain img{
    float: left;
}

.indexmain iframe{
    float:left;
}
```